# How to perform two different actions with two different intervals/durations using Timer?

Tags: java, timer

I will demonstrate what I want to achieve using code.

create timer reference
`Timer timer;`

Construct and Initialize timer

```
timer = new Timer(duration, timerAction);
timer.start();
```

Now `timerListener`

```
   AbstractAction timerAction = new AbstractAction()
   {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
           //Perform some action for duration
           jlabel.setText("A"); //action_1

           //See description under code
           jlabel.setText("B"); // action_2
      }
   };
```

The seeked scenario:

- action_1 has different duration from action_2
- Perform action_1 for duration (say duration _1)
- After completing action_1 for duration _1
- Perform action_2 for duration _2
- After completing action_2 for duration _2
- Perform action_1 for duration_1
- And so on.
- action_1 does its subsequent interval only after action_2 finishes its interval.
- action_2 does its subsequent interval only after action_1 finishes its interval.

To describe it in example: lets take these actions

```
       jlabel.setText("A"); //action_1

       jlabel.setText("B"); // action_2
```

- action_1 has different duration  from action_2
- action_1: set the text to "A" for duration 1 second.
- After performing action_1 for 1 second
- action_2: set the text to "B" for duration 2 seconds
- After performing action_2 for 2 second
- action_1: set the text to "A" for duration 1 second
- And so on.
- action_1 does its subsequent interval only after action_2 finishes its interval.
- action_2 does its subsequent interval only after action_1 finishes its interval.

....

Any idea on how to achieve it?

Comment: Are the durations necessarily closely related by a common factor (e.g., 1 and 2 seconds), or can they be completely random?

Comment: Not random, action_1 and action_2 go one after another (sequentially) each one takes its specified duration, once finished the subsequent action starts. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this :

```
public class DoubleActionTimer {

    private final Action action1;
    private final Action action2;

    private final int delay1;
    private final int delay2;

    private final Timer timer;

    private DoubleActionTimer(Action action1, int delay1, Action action2, int delay2) {
        this.timer = new Timer(delay1, new ActionSwitcher());

        this.action1 = action1;
        this.delay1 = delay1;
        this.action2 = action2;
        this.delay2 = delay2;

        this.timer.setRepeats(false);
        this.timer.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.timer.stop();
    }

    private class ActionSwitcher extends AbstractAction {

        private boolean flag = false;

        /**
         * Invoked when an action occurs.
         */
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            final Action action = flag?action2:action1;
            final int delay = flag?delay1:delay2;
            flag = !flag;

            action.actionPerformed(e);
            timer.setInitialDelay(delay);
            timer.start();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Action action1 = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Action1"+new Date());
            }
        };
        final Action action2 = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Action2 "+new Date());
            }
        };

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new DoubleActionTimer(action1, 500, action2, 3000);
            }
        });

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60);
    }
}
```